# How to get the class name of a child element with content “XX”?

Tags: jquery

How to get the class name of a child element with content “This is active”? 
I know the parent element `div` with `id` name1.

```
<div id='name1'>
    <div class='name2'>
      <span>
         <a class='active nameA'>  This is active</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class='name1'>
         <span>
               <a class='not-active'>  not active</a>
         </span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Did you have any attempt? Did you research?

Comment: Are you tring to retrieve `name2` or `nameA`?

Comment: Here http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: NameA and active. I want to know of an element is active.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```
alert($("a:contains('This is active')").attr("class"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [:contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

```
var element = $('#name1').find( "a:contains('This is active')" ), //retrieve the element
    className = element.attr('class'); //retrieve the class from element

alert('Class is ' + className);
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gLhLs5bj/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use

```
$("a:contains('This is active')").each(function() { alert(this.classList); });
```

Here, `this.classList` is a list whose elements are the attributed class names to the `<a>This is active</a>`-tag.

Answer (score 0):

The element with content "This is active" does not contain any child elements. Maybe this is what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/4sg4pn31/8/

```
var $activeChild = $("#name1").find('.active');
var $activeClass= $($activeChild).attr("class");
```

$activeChild finds the child with class active and $activeClass gets the classes of that element.